# Brief explanation for executables in a GNU/Clang Toolchain?

Tags: c++, c, compiler, commandline-build-tool

I roughly understand that cc, ld and other parts are called in a certain sequence according to schemes like Makefiles etc. Some of those commands are used to generate those configs and Makefiles. And some other tools are used to deal with libraries. But what are other parts used for? How are they called in this process? Which tool would use various parser generators? Which part is optional? Why?

Is there a brief summary get these explained on how the tools in a GNU or LLVM/Clang toolchain are organised and called in a C/C++ project building?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is a list of executables for Clang/LLVM on Mac OS X:

ar          clang           dsymutil        gperf           libtool         nmedit          rpcgen          unwinddump
as          clang++         dwarfdump       gprof           lorder          otool           segedit         vgrind
asa         cmpdylib        dyldinfo        indent          m4          pagestuff       size            what
bison           codesign_allocate   flex            install_name_tool   mig         ranlib          strip           yacc
c++         ctags           flex++          ld          mkdep           rebase          unifdef
cc          ctf_insert      gm4         lex         nm          redo_prebinding     unifdefall

Comment: All of those executables have documentation.  Have your read it?

Comment: Yes, just started from man pages. Some are too tedious, and I failed to get the whole picture.

Answer (score 2):

Most of those tools are not used in a standard project - I myself have never seen half of them.

This is the basic workflow, in terms of actual processes that are run:

```
gcc
|
v
cc1 -> as -> collect2 -> ld
```

This on its own doesn't tell you all that much.  There is no `cpp` (The preprocessor) - that is integrated into `cc1`. `cc1` itself is the backend and the "real" compiler - the `gcc` binary is a frontend for all the tools that do the actual work.  `cc1` is the preprocessor/compiler backend, which compiles to assembly.  `as` is the assembler, which produces object files.  `collect2` (I forgot about this myself, and was only made aware of it because I ran an `strace`) assists in arranging startup code in the executable (from [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html)).  Finally, `ld` links the object files and libraries into the final executable.

For the actual use of these individual components, it's generally a better idea to call `gcc` and let it figure out what to do.  For example you can run `gcc -S` on a `.c` file to produce the `.s` assemply file, or `gcc -E` to only preprocess the source file.

Basically, `man gcc` is what you want to read.  Or at least skim through.